# Changing which file is fetched depending on screen size (PHP)

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, screen-size

I know you can use this code to change "output" depending on the screen size in the container

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
</div>
```

But I have this in the beginning of my PHP, and here I want to fetch the "fpcarousel.php" if the screen is big and another PHP file if the screen is smaller.

```
<?php
  # Henter fpcarousel.php
  include("fpcarousel.php");
?>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You need JS for this, as PHP cannot detect screen sizes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966628/load-js-or-php-based-on-users-screen-size --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172806/include-php-file-only-at-certain-screen-resolutions and are possible duplicates.

Comment: The html you posted indicates twitter bootsrap 3, eg resizes based on css media queries (client side). Php is server side, so will not work like that.